# Associators of quasi-Hopf algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories

I've read in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1995.pdf) that given a **basic** finite-dimensional radically graded quasi-Hopf algebra $H$, its associator lives in degree $0$. I don't understand why this is true. The statement can be found in the first two paragraphs of the third section. The first time it could refer to the subalgebra in degree zero (which makes sense), the second time right before formula $(3.3)$.

Comment: Can you cite the paper ?

Comment: @Konkan: I added a link to the arxiv-version in the question.